# Assigning random values using ForEach to array doesnt work, but for statement works fine?

Tags: c#

If I use the `foreach` loop to assign values to an array randomly, it assigns all 0's. But if change it to a normal `for` loop, it works fine. Like below

```
 Random random = new Random();
 int[] a = new int[10];
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      a[i] = random.Next(0, 10);
   }

foreach (var item in a)
       Console.WriteLine(item);
```

The output is fine, values are random

```
5
8
...
```

But, if I use a foreach loop to assign random values, the FIRST array item has a random value and the rest are ALWAYS 0.... Why would that be?

```
 foreach (var item in a)
        {
            a[item] = random.Next(0, 10);
        } 

 foreach (var item in a)
           Console.WriteLine(item);
```

this produces

```
8
0
0
0... all zeros follow
```

Why would a normal for loop work fine, but not a foreach loop? The same foreach loops prints the values fine ?

Thank you

Comment: yes, I copy-pasted it ....

Comment: take a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: I personally find Eric Lippert's posts to be never an easy read . Informative..yes...easy to understand...nope! :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterator in a `foreach` loop (`item` in this case) represents each *value* being enumerated, not each index—as `i` does in the `for` loop. Also, when you initialize your `int[]`, every item will have the default value for `int`, which is 0.

These two factors taken together mean that when you're looping through the items in the `foreach` loop, `item` is always 0, so it always only updates the first item in the array.